# Sort RDD according to a distinct value in a column

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD[(Int, Array(Double))] like

```
1, Array(2.0,5.0,6.3) 
5, Array(1.0,3.3,9.5)
1, Array(5.0,4.2,3.1)
2, Array(9.6,6.3,2.3)
1, Array(8.5,2.5,1.2)
5, Array(6.0,2.4,7.8)
2, Array(7.8,9.1,4.2)
```

I want to sort the RDD according to the Distinct value in 1st column (1,5,2)

Required Output

```
1, Array(2.0,5.0,6.3)
1, Array(5.0,4.2,3.1)
1, Array(8.5,2.5,1.2)
5, Array(1.0,3.3,9.5)
5, Array(6.0,2.4,7.8)
2, Array(9.6,6.3,2.3)
2, Array(7.8,9.1,4.2)
```

I have tried with commands like

```
rdd.groupby()
rdd.sortby()
```

All this thing will yield output with sorted list like

```
1, Array(2.0,5.0,6.3)
1, Array(5.0,4.2,3.1)
1, Array(8.5,2.5,1.2)
2, Array(9.6,6.3,2.3)
2, Array(7.8,9.1,4.2)
5, Array(1.0,3.3,9.5)
5, Array(6.0,2.4,7.8)
```

How can I sort the RDD with distinct value is in 1st column by

```
(1,5,2)
```

Comment: Is this all of your dataset? Will you always have these 3 numbers i.e. `(1,5,2)`?

Comment: No. Dataset varies it may have different values (1,5,2,3,8,..). Wanted to arrange the data in this distinct order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first define your ordering as in your example:

```
val ordering = (1,5,2).productIterator.toList.zipWithIndex.toMap
```

And then apply it:

```
rdd.sortBy{case (k,v) => ordering(k)}
```

Comment: doesn't give the output that OP wants.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read it properly! I've updated my answer to what they want :-)

Comment: Thanks  :). Is it possible to use it as Array?
val ordering = array.productIterator.toList.zipWithIndex.toMap

Comment: yeah, array.zipWithIndex.toMap :)